# put value into a object in order

Tags: jquery

```
var dataArray = [];

function setUpData (){
name.val();
address.val();
age.val();
phone.val();

var dataObj = {name, address, age, phone};

dataObj[name] = name.val();
dataObj[address] = address.val();
dataObj[age] = age.val();
dataObj[phone] = phone.val();

dataArray.push(dataObj);

}
```

i wanted to store my data to obj and then append into array , so i am append want the object to look like this name : jason , age : 27 , something like that, but i am having error doing this.

how i gonna to achieve that ?

Comment: What is the error and where, in array u should push?

Comment: sorry i did use push , i edit it.

Comment: i have this error Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined

Comment: Where at which line, u should get it first line, as  per code shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an array (exactly like you did):

```
var dataArray = [];
```

create the object you want:

```
var person = new Object();
    person.name = 'Jason';
    person.age = 35;
```

add it to the array

```
dataArray.push(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is declaration:
    var dataObj = {name, address, age, phone}; // This is not correct.

It'd be like:
    var dataObj= {}; //empty object

Answer (score 0):

**I have made below code for you this will Print the Address value in your array.you have to initial the Array as below.**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){

        var dataArray = [];


        var dataObj = {};

        dataObj.tname ="Tst";
        dataObj.address= "Add";
        dataObj.age = "10"
        dataObj.phone = "911"
        dataArray.push(dataObj);

       console.log(dataArray.length);
        $.each( dataArray, function(index) {
             console.log( dataArray[index]["address"]);
        });

    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataArray = [];
function setUpData () {
    dataArray.push({
        name:       'Jhon',
        address:    'Miller',
        age:        7,
        phone:      9874563214,
    });
}
```